# EPPlus sorting left-to-right

Tags: c#, epplus

The new sort feature in EPPlus 4.5.1 works great when you want to sort top-to-bottom. I can't see any ability to sort left-to-right however, which is an option that exists in the Excel Sort interface options.

```
public void Sort(int[] columns, bool[] descending=null, CultureInfo culture=null, CompareOptions compareOptions=CompareOptions.None)
```

Is anyone aware of how I may be able to sort columns left to right through the ExcelRangeBase.Sort()? My specific circumstance requires sorting on at least two rows, both nested ascending.

Comment: https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=epplus

Comment: I hope u will get Idea